# could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I'm updating some values through this class, the values of createdBy and lastModifiedBy is not mandatory to update. So, I'm not passing those values from postman. It is accepting for the lastModifiedBy column but it is showing the sql exception when I'm not passing createdBy value. Why this is happening ?

```
public class SubTeamMembersUpdateRequestDTO {

    private Long id;
    private Long subTeamId;
    private Long userId;
    private Integer target;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String memberType;
    private boolean isActive;

    private String createdBy;
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}
```

The Console looks like this:

> at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  ... 111 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'created_by' cannot be null    at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1340)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   ... 160 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: Could you please provide the code which is used to update the specific entity?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, "createdBy" field is already not null in DB (since this is an update request).
I guess you should look through the saving method to DB. Looks like you try to set null to the "createdBy" field when updating the row and mysql throw an exception. Maybe you set null (just copy from SubTeamMembersUpdateRequestDTO.createBy) to DB model and save model?